# Firebase Auth: Twitter login often fails

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on a React.js + firebase app, using Twitter login (see Login.js below).

This code works most of the time (>90%), but it often fails with the following error.

Screen: Malformed response cannot be parsed from twitter.com for OAUTH1_REQUEST_TOKEN

Console: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () (verifyAssertion, line 0)

Everything works fine with Email login. This problem happens only if I use Twitter login.

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or missing something. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

```
import React from 'react';
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    callbacks: {
      // Avoid redirects after sign-in.
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (result) => {
        return false;
      }
    }
};

class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if (!this.props.user) {
            return <div>
              <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}/>
            </div>
        }
        return <Redirect to="/Main" />
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: any fix? i'm seeing the same